# Conversion of roman numb to standard numbers in C++

Tags: c++, string, char, comparison, roman-numerals

i am trying to convert a roman numbers to standard numbers in C++.
i made such arrays: unfortunately i dont know how to check the roman numbers. Beacuse let sey our s is: "MCLXIV" so when i will be going through it i will be comparing chars and "CM" or "IX" for instance are strings.

Here are my array's declaration

```
 string rzym[13] = {"I","IV","V","IX","X","XL","L","XC","C","CD","D","CM","M"};
 int arab[13] = {1,4,5,9,10,40,50,90,100,400,500,900,1000};
```

Any ideas? I would be grateful for any help!

Comment: https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=convert+roman+numerals+stackoverflow

Comment: "MCLXIV" is invalid ... "MCXLIV" will be 1144

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>

int from_roman(const std::string &roman)
{
  std::map<char, int> map =
  {
    {'M', 1000}, {'D', 500}, {'C', 100},
    {'L',   50}, {'X',  10}, {'V',   5},
    {'I',    1}
  };

  int n(0);
  const unsigned stop(roman.length() - 1);

  for (unsigned i(0); i < stop; ++i)
    if (map[roman[i]] >= map[roman[i + 1]])
      n += map[roman[i]];
    else
      n -= map[roman[i]];

  n += map[roman[stop]];

  return n;
}

int main()
{
  std::cout << "XIII = " << from_roman("XIII") << std::endl
            << "XIV = " << from_roman("XIV") << std::endl
            << "MCXLIV = " << from_roman("MCXLIV") << std::endl;;

  return 0;
}
```

You should add input data validation (empty string, invalid chars...).

Also, if you need the standard form which reflect typical "modern" usage:

- 'I', 'X', 'C' cannot appear more than three time in a row;
- 'V', 'L', 'D' cannot appear more than one time consecutively;
- 'I' can only precede 'V' and 'X', 'X' can only precede 'L' and 'C', 'C' can only precede 'D' and 'M'.

Romans where a bit inconsistent...  they had a preference for additive forms such as IIII and VIIII (the code will handle them) instead of IV and IX.

"Double subtractives" also occurred (such as IIXX instead of XVIII... the code won't handle them).

In Middle Ages, to work with large numbers (above 4000), a bar was used above a numeral (or a couple of parentheses was placed around it), to indicate multiplication by 1000. E.g.

```
(MM) = 2000000
```

So the above code doesn't work for numbers >= 4000.